# DynamoDB GSI based queries using Amplify Libraries

Tags: android, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, dynamodb-queries

For Android applications, I used to use the AppSync client to query data from DynamoDB when I use GSIs. Nowadays, I am trying to use Amplify Libraries to utilize the DataStore features. After reading the documentation and code, I realized that the Amplify Libraries don't support these kinds of queries, unless I'm mistaken. The only way I have found so far is using list and applying a filter on the results but that is not ideal considering the Read Capacity. Does anyone find a document about this issue? are there any useful plugins can be used in this case?

For clarification please refer to the following schema from AWS doc:

```
type Item @model
  @key(fields: ["orderId", "status", "createdAt"])
  @key(name: "ByStatus", fields: ["status", "createdAt"], queryField: "itemsByStatus") {
  orderId: ID!
  status: Status!
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
  name: String!
}

enum Status {
  DELIVERED
  IN_TRANSIT
  PENDING
  UNKNOWN
}
```

With AppSync you can query the data based on ByStatus GSI this way:

```java
appSyncClient.query(itemsByStatusQuery.builder().build())
```

Now, I am using Amplify API category. It seems to me that I can only use `getItem` or `listItems` queries.

I wonder if there is a way to do the same with Amplify libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As far as documentation goes, you can find information on querying the DataStore [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/data-access/q/platform/android#query-with-predicates). If you're also using the API category, you can find query documentation [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/query-data/q/platform/android#query-item).

One important thing to note is that GSIs are created/used based on your GraphQL model. The [connection](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives#generates-3) directive will generate the GSIs for you based on the relationship between the models in your schema. After doing that, you can use the generated model to issue your queries without having to explicitly specify the GSI.

Happy to help you out if you have further questions on this.

Comment: Raf, thanks for your answer, I provided more details to clarify my question. I asked the question after reading the same documents that you shared.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, that particular feature has not been implemented in Amplify yet. It is on our team's radar but we don't have an ETA on it right now. Feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues) so you can track progress if you're interested.

Since it sounds like you have both the API and DataStore categories configured, it's worth mentioning that you should be able to get an equivalent dataset by using the `Amplify.DataStore.query` and passing in the conditions (See the link in my previous response). Amplify has a synchronization process that keeps the local DataStore in sync with the API's (DynamoDb in this case). If this sounds like a suitable workaround, take a look at the [details](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/how-it-works/q/platform/android#sync-data-to-cloud) on the synchronization process.